# Apply macro on all open workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to construct a macro that is applied on all open workbooks (or all in a certain folder if easier).

I have multiple regression outputs that I'm trying to "clean" to be more presentable.

What code should I use so that the macro runs in all open spreadsheets?

```vb
Sub programmed_regression()

    'Framework
    '
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 1"
    Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 2"
    Range("E3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 3"
    Range("F3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 4"
    Range("G3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 5"
    Range("C3").Select
    
    Range("B3:G3").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    
    Range("C3:G3").Select
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
    Range("B4").Value = "Education level"
    Range("B5").Value = "std. error"
    Range("B5").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    
    Range("B6").Value = "Median income"
    Range("B7").Value = "std. error"
    Range("B7").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    
    Range("B8").Value = "Newly immigrated"
    Range("B9").Value = "std. error"
    Range("B9").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    
    Range("B10").Value = "Southern Sweden"
    Range("B11").Value = "std. error"
    Range("B11").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    
    Range("B12").Value = "Northern Sweden"
    Range("B13").Value = "std. error"
    Range("B13").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    
    Range("B14").Value = "Metropolitan areas"
    Range("B15").Value = "std. error"
    Range("B15").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
  
    Range("B16").Value = "Larger cities"
    Range("B17").Value = "std. error"
    Range("B17").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    
    Range("B18").Value = "Smaller cities"
    Range("B19").Value = "std. error"
    Range("B19").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
   
    Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Range("B21").Value = "Constant"
    Range("B22").Value = "N"
    Range("B23").Value = "Adjusted R2"
    Range("B24").Value = "Sig."
    
    ' Fetching data
    '
    'Modell 1'
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C115").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D115").Value
    
    'Modell 2'
    ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C117").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D117").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C118").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("D7").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D118").Value
    
    'Modell 3'
    ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C120").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D120").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C121").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E7").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D121").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C122").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D122").Value

    'Modell 4'
    ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C124").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D124").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C125").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F7").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D125").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F8").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C126").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F9").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D126").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F10").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C127").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F11").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D127").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F12").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C128").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F13").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D128").Value
    
    'Modell 5'
    ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C130").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D130").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C131").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G7").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D131").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G8").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C132").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D132").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G10").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C133").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G11").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D133").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G12").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C134").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G13").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D134").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G14").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C135").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G15").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D135").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G16").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C136").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G17").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D136").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G18").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C137").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G19").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D137").Value

     'Constant'
    ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C114").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("D21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C116").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C119").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C123").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C129").Value
    
    'N'
    ActiveSheet.Range("C22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D24").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("D22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D25").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D26").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D27").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D29").Value
    
    'Adjusted R2'
    ActiveSheet.Range("C23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D75").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("D23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D76").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D77").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D78").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D79").Value
    
    'Sig.'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G89").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G89").Value, "b", "")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G92").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G92").Value, "c", "")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G95").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G95").Value, "d", "")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G98").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G98").Value, "e", "")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G101").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G101").Value, "f", "")

    ActiveSheet.Range("C24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G89").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("D24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G92").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("E24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G95").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("F24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G98").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("G24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G101").Value

    Rows("5:5").Font.Italic = True
    Rows("7:7").Font.Italic = True
    Rows("9:9").Font.Italic = True
    Rows("11:11").Font.Italic = True
    Rows("13:13").Font.Italic = True
    Rows("15:15").Font.Italic = True
    Rows("17:17").Font.Italic = True
    Rows("19:19").Font.Italic = True
    
    Range("C4:G19").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"
    
    'Styling'
    Range("B20:G20").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
        
        Range("C21:G24").Select
        Selection.Font.Bold = False
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
    
            Range("C21:G21").Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"
    
            Range("C23:G24").Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"
        End With
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    
    Range("B24:G24").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

End Sub
```

*Updated code*

```
'// 2023.12.14 - Updated creating ws / inserted main prog, according to user request
'//
Sub run_workbooksss()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        wb.Activate
        
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.Activate
            programmed_regression
        Next ws
    Next wb
End Sub

Sub programmed_regression()
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newSheet = Sheets("Regression_results")
    If newSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set newSheet = Sheets.Add
        newSheet.Name = "Regression_results"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With newSheet
        .Range("C3:G3").Value = Array("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", "Model 4", "Model 5")
        .Range("B4:B24").Value = Application.Transpose(Array("Education level", "std. error", "Median income", "std. error", "Newly immigrated", "std. error", "Southern Sweden", "std. error", "Northern Sweden", "std. error", "Metropolitan areas", "std. error", "Larger cities", "std. error", "Smaller cities", "std. error", " ", "Constant", "N", "Adjusted R2", "Sig."))
        .Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        
        .Range("C3:G3").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("B5,B7,B9,B11,B13,B15,B17,B19").Font.Italic = True
        .Range("B4,B6,B8,B10,B12,B14,B16,B18").Font.Italic = False
        .Range("C21:G24").Font.Bold = False
        
        .Range("C3:G3").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("C4:G24").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range("B5,B7,B9,B11,B13,B15,B17,B19").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .Range("C3:G19").NumberFormat = "0.000"
        .Range("C21:G21").NumberFormat = "0.000"
        .Range("C23:G24").NumberFormat = "0.000"
        

        .Range("B3:G3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
        .Range("B20:G20").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
        .Range("B24:G24").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    
    ' Fetching data from Sheet1
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Set srcSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 4
        newSheet.Cells(4, i + 3).Resize(16).Value = srcSheet.Cells(114 + i * 3, 3).Resize(16).Value
        newSheet.Cells(5, i + 3).Resize(16, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Next i
    
    'Constant'
    newSheet.Range("C21").Value = srcSheet.Cells(113, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D21").Value = srcSheet.Cells(115, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E21").Value = srcSheet.Cells(118, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("F21").Value = srcSheet.Cells(122, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("G21").Value = srcSheet.Cells(128, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    
    'N'
    newSheet.Range("C22").Value = srcSheet.Cells(24, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D22").Value = srcSheet.Cells(25, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E22").Value = srcSheet.Cells(26, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("F22").Value = srcSheet.Cells(27, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("G22").Value = srcSheet.Cells(29, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    
    'R2'
    newSheet.Range("C23").Value = srcSheet.Cells(75, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D23").Value = srcSheet.Cells(76, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E23").Value = srcSheet.Cells(77, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("F23").Value = srcSheet.Cells(78, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("G23").Value = srcSheet.Cells(79, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    
    'Sig.'
    newSheet.Range("C24").Value = srcSheet.Cells(88, 7).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D24").Value = srcSheet.Cells(91, 7).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E24").Value = srcSheet.Cells(94, 7).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("F24").Value = srcSheet.Cells(97, 7).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("G24").Value = srcSheet.Cells(100, 7).Resize(1, 5).Value
    
    'Data'
    
    'Model 1'
    newSheet.Range("C4").Value = srcSheet.Cells(114, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("C5").Value = srcSheet.Cells(114, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    
    'Model 2 '
    newSheet.Range("D4").Value = srcSheet.Cells(116, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D5").Value = srcSheet.Cells(116, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D6").Value = srcSheet.Cells(117, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D7").Value = srcSheet.Cells(117, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    
    'Model 3'
    newSheet.Range("D4").Value = srcSheet.Cells(119, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D5").Value = srcSheet.Cells(119, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D6").Value = srcSheet.Cells(120, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D7").Value = srcSheet.Cells(120, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D6").Value = srcSheet.Cells(121, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("D7").Value = srcSheet.Cells(121, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    
    'Model 4'
    newSheet.Range("E4").Value = srcSheet.Cells(123, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E5").Value = srcSheet.Cells(123, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E6").Value = srcSheet.Cells(124, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E7").Value = srcSheet.Cells(124, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E8").Value = srcSheet.Cells(125, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E9").Value = srcSheet.Cells(125, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E10").Value = srcSheet.Cells(126, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E11").Value = srcSheet.Cells(126, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E12").Value = srcSheet.Cells(127, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E13").Value = srcSheet.Cells(127, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    
    'Model 5'
    newSheet.Range("E4").Value = srcSheet.Cells(129, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E5").Value = srcSheet.Cells(129, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E6").Value = srcSheet.Cells(130, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E7").Value = srcSheet.Cells(130, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E8").Value = srcSheet.Cells(131, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E9").Value = srcSheet.Cells(131, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E10").Value = srcSheet.Cells(132, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E11").Value = srcSheet.Cells(132, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E12").Value = srcSheet.Cells(133, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E13").Value = srcSheet.Cells(133, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E14").Value = srcSheet.Cells(134, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E15").Value = srcSheet.Cells(134, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E16").Value = srcSheet.Cells(135, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E17").Value = srcSheet.Cells(135, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E18").Value = srcSheet.Cells(136, 3).Resize(1, 5).Value
    newSheet.Range("E19").Value = srcSheet.Cells(136, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value
    
    For i = 0 To 4
        srcSheet.Cells(88 + i * 3, 7).Value = Replace(srcSheet.Cells(88 + i * 3, 7).Value, Chr(98 - i), "")
        srcSheet.Cells(91 + i * 3, 7).Value = Replace(srcSheet.Cells(91 + i * 3, 7).Value, Chr(98 - i), "")
        
        newSheet.Cells(24, i + 3).Value = srcSheet.Cells(88 + i * 3, 7).Value
        newSheet.Cells(24, i + 3).Value = srcSheet.Cells(91 + i * 3, 7).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

How it should look
[image]

How it looks
[image]

Comment: A worksheet is a tab within a workbook file.  You use the terms a little interchangeably, and it make it harder to follow what you're looking for.

Comment: `Dim wb As Workbook : For Each wb In Application.Workbooks : [do something with wb] : Next wb`

Comment: My bad! Guess it is due to language barriers. English is not my first (nor my working) language.

As you've seem to figured out I meant open "workbooks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to Tim's comment, if you want to apply *programmed_regression* macro to **all** open workbooks instead of worksheets (i.e. tabs within an excel file), then try below,

```vb
'// Added Worksheet name
Sub run_workbooks()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        wb.Activate
        
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.Activate
            programmed_regression
        Next ws
    Next wb
End Sub

Sub programmed_regression()
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Set newSheet = Sheets.Add
    newSheet.Name = "Regression_results"
    
    ' //
    ' copy/paste your vb here
    ' ...
    ' //

End Sub
```

If were supposed, *programmed_regression* to run through all active **worksheets**, i.e. tabs within active file,

```vb
Sub run_worksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        programmed_regression
    Next ws
End Sub

Sub programmed_regression()
    ' //
    ' copy/paste your vb here
    ' ...
    ' //
End Sub
```

#### Modified snippet

*Strictly follows original fetch pattern*

```vb
'// 2023.12.14 - Updated creating ws / inserted main prog, according to user request
'// 2023.12.15 - Reverted
'//
Sub run_workbooks()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        wb.Activate

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.Activate
            programmed_regression
        Next ws
    Next wb
End Sub

Sub programmed_regression()
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newSheet = Sheets("Regression_results")
    If newSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set newSheet = Sheets.Add
        newSheet.Name = "Regression_results"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    newSheet.Select
    
        'Framework
        '
        Range("C3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 1"
        Range("D3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 2"
        Range("E3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 3"
        Range("F3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 4"
        Range("G3").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Model 5"
        Range("C3").Select
        
        Range("B3:G3").Select
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
        
        Range("C3:G3").Select
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With
        
        Range("B4").Value = "Education level"
        Range("B5").Value = "std. error"
        Range("B5").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        
        Range("B6").Value = "Median income"
        Range("B7").Value = "std. error"
        Range("B7").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        
        Range("B8").Value = "Newly immigrated"
        Range("B9").Value = "std. error"
        Range("B9").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        
        Range("B10").Value = "Southern Sweden"
        Range("B11").Value = "std. error"
        Range("B11").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        
        Range("B12").Value = "Northern Sweden"
        Range("B13").Value = "std. error"
        Range("B13").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        
        Range("B14").Value = "Metropolitan areas"
        Range("B15").Value = "std. error"
        Range("B15").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
      
        Range("B16").Value = "Larger cities"
        Range("B17").Value = "std. error"
        Range("B17").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        
        Range("B18").Value = "Smaller cities"
        Range("B19").Value = "std. error"
        Range("B19").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
       
        Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
        Range("B21").Value = "Constant"
        Range("B22").Value = "N"
        Range("B23").Value = "Adjusted R2"
        Range("B24").Value = "Sig."
        
        ' Fetching data
        '
        'Modell 1'
        ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C115").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D115").Value
        
        'Modell 2'
        ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C117").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D117").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("D6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C118").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("D7").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D118").Value
        
        'Modell 3'
        ActiveSheet.Range("E4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C120").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D120").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("E6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C121").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("E7").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D121").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C122").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D122").Value
    
        'Modell 4'
        ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C124").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D124").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C125").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F7").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D125").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F8").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C126").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F9").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D126").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F10").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C127").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F11").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D127").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F12").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C128").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F13").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D128").Value
        
        'Modell 5'
        ActiveSheet.Range("G4").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C130").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G5").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D130").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C131").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G7").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D131").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G8").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C132").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G9").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D132").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G10").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C133").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G11").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D133").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G12").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C134").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G13").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D134").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G14").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C135").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G15").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D135").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G16").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C136").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G17").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D136").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G18").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C137").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G19").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D137").Value
    
         'Constant'
        ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C114").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("D21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C116").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("E21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C119").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C123").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G21").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C129").Value
        
        'N'
        ActiveSheet.Range("C22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D24").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("D22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D25").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("E22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D26").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D27").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G22").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D29").Value
        
        'Adjusted R2'
        ActiveSheet.Range("C23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D75").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("D23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D76").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("E23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D77").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D78").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G23").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D79").Value
        
        'Sig.'
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G89").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G89").Value, "b", "")
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G92").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G92").Value, "c", "")
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G95").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G95").Value, "d", "")
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G98").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G98").Value, "e", "")
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G101").Value = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G101").Value, "f", "")
    
        ActiveSheet.Range("C24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G89").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("D24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G92").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("E24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G95").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("F24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G98").Value
        ActiveSheet.Range("G24").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G101").Value
    
        Rows("5:5").Font.Italic = True
        Rows("7:7").Font.Italic = True
        Rows("9:9").Font.Italic = True
        Rows("11:11").Font.Italic = True
        Rows("13:13").Font.Italic = True
        Rows("15:15").Font.Italic = True
        Rows("17:17").Font.Italic = True
        Rows("19:19").Font.Italic = True
        
        Range("C4:G19").Select
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With
    
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"
        
        'Styling'
        Range("B20:G20").Select
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
            
            Range("C21:G24").Select
            Selection.Font.Bold = False
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
        
            Range("C21:G21").Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"
        
            Range("C23:G24").Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"
        End With
        End With
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
        
                Range("B24:G24").Select
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

End Sub
```

The vb output with dummy data as below,
[image]

Comment: Hopefully just a quick follow up question: If I would like to name the created sheet to "Regression_results", what should I edit? 

I've tried:

Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Regression_results"

But that messed things up.

Comment: @MikaelBruér no worries mate, you were in the right path but needed to define a newSheet; added a couple lines on WorkBook section. Hope it helps.

Comment: Great many thanks for help @Derby9421 I have probably done something that I don't know about. When I'm running the macro it seems to create more than one sheet (up to four). This results in "run time error 1004 name already taken". I had to update the code because of a changed output in SPSS. Could I have done something there? I have put an updated code in post. –

Comment: @MikaelBruér fully understood. I tried to follow your structure and summarised the script in the answer. Not sure it works 100% due to your new demand to meet SPSS (or any sub-module), but may help you to play around to twist to your needs.

Comment: I don't seem to get it working @Derby9421

The issue this time is that the table is filled with other data than it should be. I've put the updated code, and two images showing how it should look and how it looks.

Comment: @MikaelBruér Thanks for the note and uploaded image outlining the expected results. I reverted (now with min amendments) the code back to the orig fetching snippet, which aligns with the structure of the original vb you presented, and it can indeed make it easier for your further modifications in later stages. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Apply Code to All Visible Workbooks

**Loop Through the Workbooks**

```vb
Sub UpdateWorkbooks()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If wb.Windows(1).Visible Then ' e.g. to not mess up 'PERSONAL.xlsb'
            ApplyRegression wb
        End If
    Next wb

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Workbooks updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Apply to Each Workbook**

```vb
Sub ApplyRegression(ByVal wb As Workbook)

    Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet

    With wb
        Set sws = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set dws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With
    
    With dws
        
        'Framework
        
        With .Range("B3:G3").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        
        With .Range("C3:G3")
            .Value = Array( _
                "Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3", "Model 4", "Model 5")
            .Font.Bold = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With
        
        .Range("B4").Value = "Education level"
        .Range("B6").Value = "Median income"
        .Range("B8").Value = "Newly immigrated"
        .Range("B10").Value = "Southern Sweden"
        .Range("B12").Value = "Northern Sweden"
        .Range("B14").Value = "Metropolitan areas"
        .Range("B16").Value = "Larger cities"
        .Range("B18").Value = "Smaller cities"
        
        With .Range("B5,B7,B9,B11,B13,B15,B17,B19")
            .Value = "std. error"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End With
        
        .Range("B21").Value = "Constant"
        .Range("B22").Value = "N"
        .Range("B23").Value = "Adjusted R2"
        .Range("B24").Value = "Sig."
        
        .Columns("B").AutoFit
               
        ' Fetching data
        
        'Modell 1'
        .Range("C4").Value = sws.Range("C115").Value
        .Range("C5").Value = sws.Range("D115").Value
        'Modell 2'
        .Range("D4").Value = sws.Range("C117").Value
        .Range("D5").Value = sws.Range("D117").Value
        .Range("D6").Value = sws.Range("C118").Value
        .Range("D7").Value = sws.Range("D118").Value
        'Modell 3'
        .Range("E4").Value = sws.Range("C120").Value
        .Range("E5").Value = sws.Range("D120").Value
        .Range("E6").Value = sws.Range("C121").Value
        .Range("E7").Value = sws.Range("D121").Value
        .Range("E8").Value = sws.Range("C122").Value
        .Range("E9").Value = sws.Range("D122").Value
        'Modell 4'
        .Range("F4").Value = sws.Range("C124").Value
        .Range("F5").Value = sws.Range("D124").Value
        .Range("F6").Value = sws.Range("C125").Value
        .Range("F7").Value = sws.Range("D125").Value
        .Range("F8").Value = sws.Range("C126").Value
        .Range("F9").Value = sws.Range("D126").Value
        .Range("F10").Value = sws.Range("C127").Value
        .Range("F11").Value = sws.Range("D127").Value
        .Range("F12").Value = sws.Range("C128").Value
        .Range("F13").Value = sws.Range("D128").Value
        'Modell 5'
        .Range("G4").Value = sws.Range("C130").Value
        .Range("G5").Value = sws.Range("D130").Value
        .Range("G6").Value = sws.Range("C131").Value
        .Range("G7").Value = sws.Range("D131").Value
        .Range("G8").Value = sws.Range("C132").Value
        .Range("G9").Value = sws.Range("D132").Value
        .Range("G10").Value = sws.Range("C133").Value
        .Range("G11").Value = sws.Range("D133").Value
        .Range("G12").Value = sws.Range("C134").Value
        .Range("G13").Value = sws.Range("D134").Value
        .Range("G14").Value = sws.Range("C135").Value
        .Range("G15").Value = sws.Range("D135").Value
        .Range("G16").Value = sws.Range("C136").Value
        .Range("G17").Value = sws.Range("D136").Value
        .Range("G18").Value = sws.Range("C137").Value
        .Range("G19").Value = sws.Range("D137").Value
         'Constant'
        .Range("C21").Value = sws.Range("C114").Value
        .Range("D21").Value = sws.Range("C116").Value
        .Range("E21").Value = sws.Range("C119").Value
        .Range("F21").Value = sws.Range("C123").Value
        .Range("G21").Value = sws.Range("C129").Value
        'N'
        .Range("C22").Value = sws.Range("D24").Value
        .Range("D22").Value = sws.Range("D25").Value
        .Range("E22").Value = sws.Range("D26").Value
        .Range("F22").Value = sws.Range("D27").Value
        .Range("G22").Value = sws.Range("D29").Value
        'Adjusted R2'
        .Range("C23").Value = sws.Range("D75").Value
        .Range("D23").Value = sws.Range("D76").Value
        .Range("E23").Value = sws.Range("D77").Value
        .Range("F23").Value = sws.Range("D78").Value
        .Range("G23").Value = sws.Range("D79").Value
        
        'Sig.'
        With sws ' are you sure you want to modify the source?
            .Range("G89").Value = Replace(.Range("G89").Value, "b", "")
            .Range("G92").Value = Replace(.Range("G92").Value, "c", "")
            .Range("G95").Value = Replace(.Range("G95").Value, "d", "")
            .Range("G98").Value = Replace(.Range("G98").Value, "e", "")
            .Range("G101").Value = Replace(.Range("G101").Value, "f", "")
        End With
        .Range("C24").Value = sws.Range("G89").Value
        .Range("D24").Value = sws.Range("G92").Value
        .Range("E24").Value = sws.Range("G95").Value
        .Range("F24").Value = sws.Range("G98").Value
        .Range("G24").Value = sws.Range("G101").Value
    
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, Union(.Rows(5), .Rows(7), .Rows(9), _
                .Rows(11), .Rows(13), .Rows(15), .Rows(17), .Rows(19)))
            .Font.Italic = True
        End With
        
        With .Range("C4:G19")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
            .NumberFormat = "0.000"
        End With
    
        'Styling'
        
        With .Range("B20:G20").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        
        With .Range("C21:G24")
            .Font.Bold = False
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
        End With
        
        .Range("C21:G21,C23:G24").NumberFormat = "0.000"
        
        With .Range("B24:G24").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
       
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How do this differ from the code that Derby9421 posted (that worked)? And where shoud I place the codes if I decide to use this instead?

Comment: Code that relies on a specific workbook or worksheet being active for it to run correctly can be brittle and difficult to debug.  This code doesn't rely on ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet.   See here for more about avoiding Select/Activate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: There's nothing to it, just put the code in a standard module e.g. `Module1`, `Module2`, ... etc. (`VBE->Insert->Module`), and run the `UpdateWorkbooks` procedure. In each open workbook, it will add a sheet that will be populated with the data from each workbook's `Sheet1`.

Comment: Great thanks @VBasic2008 ! It seems to work flawlessly, but only applies to one workbook, not to all.